Looking for an anime style show with a skyship and kids flying planes from either the 80s or 90s
I am looking for an animated series that was on South African television in the 90s. It may have been broadcast in the 80s in other parts of the world. It had to have been an Anime type show since the characters had the big eyes.
It was about two brothers and their sister who lived on a skyboat/blimp type thing with their parents and grandfather. 
They also flew planes, the oldest brother had a green plane, the youngest a red and white one and the sister flew a green one as well. 
All the characters were humans.
I am certain that the series did not include any space travel.
This is all I can remember for certain from the show. 
Something else that I recall but am not too sure about is that there may have been a robotic assistant to the grandfather. And also that one of the planes was a cargo type aircraft. The red and white plane would often go into super sonic mode and change it's tip from s stump nosed plane into a sharp nosed one.
I have been scouring the internet for days and so Far I have ruled out:
Laputa: Castle in the Sky (Movie not series),
Skyland (Too new),
Last Exile (Also too new),
Swat Kats (The Anthropomorphic animals),
Koala brothers (Same reason as above),
Skyhunter (part of the look and read series)
Wing Commander Academy (It was all in space)
It doesn't seem to be Future boy Conan either.
I think I found a picture of the ship


This has been bugging me for a while since the description seemed so familiar! A few lucky searches later and I believe the show you're looking for is:
Kinkyuu Hasshin Saver Kids


Matsugorou is a vile doctor who plots out a plan to take over the world by commanding his own robotic army. The only chance the world has is a group of three brothers that make up a team called the Emergengy Departure Saver Kids.

Opening sequence:




Yes, OMW thank you so much.You have just solved YEARS of hunting for me.

@Nic Glad to have been of help! My younger siblings used to watch this (I didn't) and it matched your excellent description.
